# Discord JS - How to get image url from JSON?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

Hello I am trying to isolate a image - `src=\"https:\/\/steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net\/economy\/image\/6TMcQ7eX6E0EZl2byXi7vaVKyDk_zQLX05x6eLCFM9neAckxGDf7qU2e2gu64OnAeQ7835Ff5GLNfCk4nReh8DEiv5dbPK47pbcyR_m4DQ68Ofs\/62fx62f\"` from https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/252490/Alien%20Red/render?currency=1&format=json and put it into a embed, I am using node fetch to get the overall json from the site how would I go about doing this? I currently have a inefficient way of doing it (getting every character) and it does not work at some points. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There will probably be a better way to do this, but I've thrown this together:
`/(?!src=\\?)\"(.*?)\"/g`

Just match this with the return and you will have your URL.

Comment: Thanks man, worked perfectly and decided to look into and read into Regex.

Answer (score 0):

If you are making this a static thing (ie. it will be ONLY this image, and will not be editable depending on a command or variable, then just put it as a string & make that the embed's image.

If not, then fetch the contents, then get the `results_html` portion of it. Then, find where it says "<img" and isolate it until the next ">". Sub string that bad boy from where is says `src=` to when it sees `\"` . (or `"`  depending on how it interprets this), and  use that sub string as the embed's image attachment.